# .sql file not returning the column headers in csv file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus, export-to-csv

The below code is in batch file script(.bat file) which calls the sql file.

```
del C:\SREE\csvfile.csv    
sqlplus SERVERNAME/Test123@ldptstb @C:\SREE\sree.sql    
set from_email="SENDER_EMAIL_ID"     
set to_email="TO_EMAIL_ID"     
set cc_email="CC_EMAIL_ID"    
set email_message="Csv file from application server"    
set body_email=C:\SREE\sree.txt    
set sendmail=C:\Interface\sqlldr\common\SENDMAIL.VBS    
set interface_log=C:\SREE\csvfile.csv    
cscript %sendmail% -F %from_email% -T %to_email% -C %cc_email% -S %email_message% -B %body_email%  -A %interface_log% -O "ATTACHFILE" -A %body_email% -O "FILEASTEXT"
exit
```

This below content in .sql file code which executes the SQL Query and stores the data into csv file:

```
set pagesize 0    
set heading on    
set feedback off    
set trimspool on    
set linesize 32767    
set termout off    
set verify off    
set colsep ","    
spool C:\SREE\csvfile.csv    
SELECT Name, ID, Email, Role, Status FROM csvfile    
exit
```

The output is stored in csv file and getting this file in email.

But theproblem is I am not getting the Column Names in the csv file. I had tried in many scenarios to get the names as a cloumn headings in csv file.

Anyone please help me out with the code to get the column names in the csv file.. thanks in advance...

Comment: I believe you are using `Oracle`. From your command which uses `sqlplus`

Comment: I am using Oracle tool and I am able to get the data in the csv file in the email attachment. But I am not able to get the Column names in the csv file.

Answer (score 3):

When you `set pagesize 0` [headings are suppressed](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve040.htm#i2699247):

> **SET PAGES[IZE] {14 | n}**
>   Sets the number of lines on each page of output. You can set `PAGESIZE` to zero to suppress all headings, page breaks, titles, the initial blank line, and other formatting information.

That's the case even if you then explicitly `set headings on`.

You can either set `pagesize` to something very large instead, or possibly more helpfully as you probably don't really want the separator line of dashes, generate them yourself with:

```
PROMPT Name,ID,Email,Role,Status
```

... before your `select` statement.

Comment: Hi Alex Poole, It works fine with the PROMPT. Really really Thanks alot for your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

Use `GENERATE_HEADER` configuration setting amd set it to `Yes` like

```
SET GENERATE_HEADER = 'Yes'
```

See this related thread here https://community.oracle.com/thread/2325171?start=0&tstart=0