# How to Generate Sqlplus to csv file?

Tags: oracle, bash, shell, csv, sqlplus

i am trying to generate the csv file out of oracle SQLPLUS by shell script, I am getting headers repeated multiple times and also null values are coming at the end of the line,

```
echo "****************************************************************"

echo "Started may at : " $(date +"%r")

sqlplus -s ETLUSER/ETL@//10.135.23.232:1521/ODS<<EOF >/dev/null

SPOOL wfa_may.csv

SELECT MAC_ADDRESS ||','||
CRM_BP_ID    || ',' || 
EVENT_TIMESTAMP  || ',' || 
ACCT_INPUT_OCTETS || ',' || 
ACCT_OUTPUT_OCTETS || ',' || 
ACCT_INPUT_PACKETS || ',' || 
ACCT_OUTPUT_PACKETS || ',' || 
ACCT_SESSION_TIME || ',' || 
NAS_IDENTIFIER || ',' || 
EXTRACTION_DATE || ',' || 
RECORD_DATE || ',' || 
LAST_MODIFIED_DATE || ',' || 
ETL_BATCH_ID || ',' || 
ETL_PROCESS_ID || ',' || 
RECORD_LOAD_TIMESTAMP FROM DBAS.S_WFA_ACCOUNTING_MSG where to_char(EVENT_TIMESTAMP,'MON') = 'MAY';

exit

EOF

echo "Ended may at : " $(date +"%r")

echo  "****************************************************************"
```

from NAS_IDENTIFIER i am not able to find any values displayed in file.

Can anyone help me whats wrong ?

Comment: Are any of the other columns strings which might have commas in them? They don't likely to from the names but that can throw off the CSV. (Slightly curious why you're spooling rather than just redirecting the output to a files, rather than /dev/null; but that's not really relevant. And you know you can split your select onto multiple lines in the script to make it more readable, right?)

Comment: Headers are repeating and line breaks happening ??             set termout off
set feedback off
set head on
set verify off
set echo off
set linesize 30000
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on will these help ??

Comment: [`set pagesize 0` will suppress all headers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22738117/266304), not just the repeating ones; you can set a large number to only see them once. Or [create your own](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23376028/266304). You may need to set `linesize` - after your edit I'm not sure what you're seeing, e.g. if the data is wrapping onto multiple lines, or being truncated. Showing some current output and the corresponding values from the table might clarify.

Comment: You can see my updated answer with demonstration and example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either `set head off` or `set pages 0` in the script.

Answer (score 0):

> I am getting headers repeated multiple times

Setting required `linesize` should work. Anyway, have a look at this :

**Update : Demonstration of my suggestion**

```
SET COLSEP ,
SET PAGESIZE 0
SET LINESIZE 1000
SET trimspool ON 

SPOOL "D:\EMP_DATA.csv"

Select *
From Scott.EMP
/

SPOOL OFF
```

**And the spooled csv file looks like this :**

[image]

Comment: Did you mean setting required pagesize, not linesize? That won't affect heading repetition - just if they split across lines? And the `colsep` isn't doing anything as it's all concatenated into one column. If you just use that, with individual columns preserved, then they're still padded out to the same width, which looks odd - and I think padding is kept if the file is opened in Excel say, which may not be ideal.

Comment: OK, but my point still stands - the string values (but not dates and numbers) are still padded when Excel opens the file, so it has `SMITH               ` rather than just `SMITH`. Which may or may not matter. I prefer concatenation for that reason, personally, but YMMV.

Comment: @William, you are welcome. So, did my answer help you? As I see you voted other post as an answer. I am now curious yo know. Please feedback.